# jquery: do something when 'hover' is unbinded on '.myBox'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

is it possible in Jquery to have it so, when i unbind hover, on `.myBox`, it does something? I wanted to add that into the first plugin i'm making, wasn't sure how?

there's specific things I want to always be done when unbinding hover on specific elements, like css('cursor', 'default') and a few other things. Is there a way to have stuff triggered when something is unbound, without having to do that stuff when declaring the unbind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to extend the `unbind` function itself:

```
(function ($) {

   var unbind = jQuery.fn.unbind;

   jQuery.fn.unbind = function(type, func) {
       var matchedElements = this.filter('#matchedElement1,#matchedElement2');
       if (matchedElements.length && typeof type == "string" && type == "mouseover") {
          // Blah Blah, whatever you wanted to do (do it to matchedElements rather than this).
       }

       return unbind.apply(this, arguments); // Call the actual unbind handler.
   };

   /* The rest of your plugin */

}(jQuery));
```